# T-SQL : partitioning using a case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, partitioning, flags

I have the following table :

```
| RoomID | OrderID | Occupancy | Status        |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------------+
| 01     | 101     | Vacant    | inspection    |
| 01     | 102     | Occupied  | Preservation  |
| 01     | 103     | Occupied  | inspection    |
| 01     | 104     | Vacant    | inspection    |
| 02     | 201     | Vacant    | inspection    |
| 02     | 202     | Occupied  | inspection    |
| 02     | 203     | Vacant    | inspection    |
| 03     | 301     | Vacant    | inspection    |
| 03     | 302     | Occupied  | inspection    |
| 03     | 303     | Occupied  | Preservation  |
| 03     | 304     | Occupied  | Preservation  |
| 04     | 401     | Occupied  | inspection    |
| 04     | 402     | Occupied  | inspection    |
| 04     | 403     | Vacant    | Preservation  |
| 04     | 404     | Occupied  | inspection    |
```

I need to pull my data on a `RoomID` level where the `Occupancy` = 'Occupied' and `Status` = 'Preservation' in any instance of a given `RoomID`.

The result should look like the following:

```
| RoomID | Flag    |
+--------+---------+
| 01     | 1       |
| 02     | 0       |
| 03     | 1       |
| 04     | 0       |
```

I have an impression that this is easy but I cannot see it at the moment, thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.

```
select roomid,
count(distinct case when Occupancy = 'Occupied' and Status = 'Preservation' then 1 end) flag
from tablename
group by roomid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below query using UNION.

```
;with cte_1
 AS
( SELECT DISTINCT RoomId
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE Occupancy='Occupied' AND Status='Predervation')
  SELECT RoomId,1 Status
  FROM cte_1
  UNON
  SELECT DISTINCT RoomId,0 Status
   FROM YourTable t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte_1 c
               WHERE t.RoomId=c.RoomId)
```